# Javascript. Reverse order of words in string, but not special characters

Tags: javascript, strings

Hello I am hoping someone can provide me feedback on my solution to this prob. If there are additional edge cases I should consider etc. Thank you!

The question: "Given a sentence with a set of delimiters, reverse the order of the words in the sentence and keep the delimiters in place."

````
let isAlpha = (char) => {
  let pat = /[a-zA-z]/igm;     // match any alphabetic character
  if(char.match(pat)){
      return true
  } else {
      return false
  }
}

function reverse(s){
  
  let specialArr = []   

  for(ltr of s){ 
    if(!isAlpha(ltr)){                        // pull out all special characters in order
      specialArr.push(ltr)
    } 
  }
  
  let regCharArr = s.split(/[^a-z]/ig).reverse()     // use split to pull out all words separated by non alpha characters. then reverse
  
  let result = []                                    // init result array
  
  if(isAlpha(s[0])){
    result = regCharArr.flatMap((val, idx) => [val, specialArr[idx]])   //use flatmap to combine the two arrays...if origin array starts with letter, combine special array into reg array
  }
  
  if(!isAlpha(s[0])){
    result = specialArr.flatMap((val, idx) => [val, regCharArr[idx]])    // vice versa
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){         // remove any undefineds
    if(result[i] === undefined){
      result.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
  return result.join('')
}


// let sentence = "one|twotwo/three:four"  // four|three/twotwo:one
let sentence = "|brian/steve:chris|jon"     // |jon/chris:steve|brian

console.log(reverse(sentence))

```
````

Comment: [There is an answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124459/how-does-one-reverse-the-word-order-within-a-string-but-does-keep-the-order-of-t/66125409#66125409)

Comment: Thank you! I just took a look at your response. My solution breaks on spaces too..where as yours does not.

Comment: Could you add some testcases to describe what the requirement is? For example, what is "word" means here? Is "twenty-three" a single word or two? Will there always be some words between two delimiter characters? What is the expected output for `"#a!!b?c"`?

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation of `isAlpha` ...

```
let isAlpha = (char) => {
  // match any alphabetic character.
  let pat = /[a-zA-z]/igm;

  if(char.match(pat)){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

... can be refactored into something as short as this ...

```
function isAlpha(char) {
  return (/[a-zA-z]/).test(char);
};
```

... or maybe even that ...

```
function isAlpha(char) {
  // \w matches any word character
  // and is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]
  return (/\w/).test(char);
};
```

Why is that?

`isAlpha` gets invoked from within `reverse` always by providing a single character. Thus the regex can be simplified from `/[a-zA-z]/igm` to `/[a-zA-z]/`. Since `isAlpha` is supposed to return a boolean value do not use `match` and do no not return either `true` or `false` separately but use [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead which already provides the correct return value.

Thats all so far but I will continue looking through the code, since as of now I don't understand why one wants to test a string stepwise character by character.

There is an answer of mine, regarding your question at StackOverflow. Maybe you get some inspiration from an alternative approach.